Verifying a spectral integral equality
I'm stucked when reading Chemin's Mathematical Geophysics An introduction to rotating fluids and the Navier-Stokes equations. On page 38 he applied spectral theorem to Stokes operator $\mathcal{A}$, induced a family of orthogonal projections $\{\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}}$ on $\mathcal{H}$. Then in corollary 2.2 he wrote:
For any $u\in\mathcal{V}_{\sigma}$, we have
$$
\|(\mathrm{Id}-\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda})u\|_{L^2}\le\frac{1}{\lambda^{\frac{1}{2}}}\|u\|_{\mathcal{V}_{\sigma}}.
$$
In his proof he wrote:
We notice that if $u$ is in $\mathcal{V}_{\sigma}$ then
$$
\|(\mathrm{Id}-\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda})u\|_{L^2}^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}}d((\mathrm{Id}-\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda})u|u).\qquad\qquad(1)
$$
My problem is that how do we get (1)? Precisely speaking I can't figure out where $u\in\mathcal{V}_{\sigma}$ (i.e. $\nabla\cdot u=0$) is used. I've tried to use the following equality:
$$
\|u\|_{L^2}^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}}d(\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}u|u),\qquad\qquad(2)
$$
then I got
\begin{align*}
\|(\mathrm{Id}-\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda})u\|_{L^2}^2&=\int_{\mathbb{R}_{\lambda'}}d(\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda'}(\mathrm{Id}-\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda})u|(\mathrm{Id}-\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda})u)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}_{\lambda'}}d((\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda'}-\boldsymbol{P}_{\min\{\lambda',\lambda\}})u|(\mathrm{Id}-\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda})u)\\
&=\int_{\lambda}^{\infty}d((\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda'}-\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda})u|(\mathrm{Id}-\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda})u)\\
&=\int_{\lambda}^{\infty}d((\mathrm{Id}-\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda})(\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda'}-\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda})u|u)\\
&=\int_{\lambda}^{\infty}d((\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda'}-\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda})u|u)\\
\end{align*}
But I don't know what I should do next. Also, I'm trying to understand (1) intuitively. I think since $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow+\infty}\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}=\mathrm{Id},\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}=0(\lambda<0)$, if $\{\mathrm{Id}-\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}}$ and $\{\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}}$ are the same thing (the former one is just the latter one written backwards), then (1) is a direct result from (2). Am I right?
